# Black texture when loading .obj and .mtl files three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Need some help with loading files to three.js. We are creating 3d models with Marvelous Designer app and showing them in web with three.js library.

The problem is that some of loaded object has black texture. I tried to add light but that didn't help me. Sometimes everything is fine with object (meaning that it has natural colors instead of black texture)
For example: 
[image]

And:
[image]

Both objects were created the same way

Here is my code:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var lighting = false;
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    scene.add(ambient);
    var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
    keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);
    var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
    fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);
    var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();


    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setBaseUrl(params.folder);
    mtlLoader.setPath(params.folder);
    mtlLoader.load(params.mtl, function (materials) {

        materials.preload();

        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath(params.folder);
        objLoader.load(params.obj, function (object) {


            scene.add(object);

        }, onProgress, onError);

    }, onProgress, onError);
```

Comment: did you try to add `THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );` before `var mtlLoader = ...;`

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks for the reply. That didn't help:(

Comment: by the way, any error messages in your console log?

Comment: @prisoner well....I solved this problem. Sometimes it's bad idea too use outdated library. I've updated library and now it works. Thanks for participating